# skiasharp - SkBitmap.Decode(string filename) returns null

Tags: xamarin.forms, skiasharp

I want to decode drawable image in `SKBitmap`. for that I use following

`var bitmap = SKBitmap.Decode("Tulips.jpg");`

but I get null bitmap. because of this I have to convert it into `byte[]` using memory stream and it takes too much time. I tried to place full path of drawable image but no success. I also tried changing `Build Action` for that image.

Any help would be appreciated !!

Edit :- 
Thanks @Jason for commenting.
Do you mean like this ??

`var filestream = new SKFilestream("Tulips.jpg");
var bitmap = SKBitmap.Decode(filestream);`

But it still returns null. I tried different paths also. But no success.

Can you please provide small code snippet ?? That will be very helpful. 
Thanks !!

Comment: you can decode directly from the FileStream without converting to byte[] first

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: are you sure your FileStream is not null?  You can also use a standard .NET stream.

Comment: I solved it using standard .net stream. Thank you :)